# Facebook connect cookie disappearing at first page change, on Google Chrome v11

Tags: authentication, cookies, google-chrome, facebook

I have been developing two websites that rely on [Facebook Connect javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). The facebook sessions of these websites have been working well on many browsers until I switched to Google Chrome 11... For some reason, it only works in "private" mode now. And a friend (also using a Mac) experienced the same difficulties today.

In order to understand what went wrong, I observed cookies (using the development panel of Google Chome) while logging in and navigating on my websites. When I login with my facebook account, a `fbs_` cookie is stored. It is successfully transmitted to the server when requesting a first page. But, as soon as the page is displayed, the cookie disappears, requiring me to login again with facebook connect!

I tried to force this cookie using a `set-cookie` response header from the server, but it didn't help.

When I use another browser (firefox, safari) or Google Chrome's "private" mode, both websites work well.

Do you have any clue about the reasons and the solution of that problem?

**Update: The problem disappeared the following day, without having to do anything... That's weird!**

Comment: Try sending this `P3P: CP=HONK` in the headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing FB.Init() on each page?

Take a look here: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

And ensure that the cookie param is set to true.

FB.init({
     appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
     status : true, // check login status
     cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
   });

Comment: Yes, I do this on every page.

Comment: Are you loading the all.js asynchronously? You might try just the synchronous load.

Comment: yes i do, but synchronous loading of javascript files slows down page loading... but this is a good idea to try if the problem shows up again! thanx